# How to add perspective listeners

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

In our application, we have 4 views (View 1, 2, 3 & 4) and 3 perspectives (perspective 1, 2 and 3).

The perspectives are built by implementing `IPerspectivefactory` and views are built by extending viewPart.

We are facing a situation where we want to set the focus to a particular view in case of any of the perspective is selected.

For ex, Consider View 1 as a common view which will be displayed under all the 3 perspectives. We want to set focus to View1 whenever we select any perspective.

How to add listeners to the perspectives?

We know that we have to add `IPerspectiveListerner` to listen to the perspective changes but we are not sure where to add it so that we get the execution control inside the methods which we have implemented under `IPerspectiveListener`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following code:

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().addPerspectiveListener(new IPerspectiveListener() {
  @Override
  public void perspectiveChanged(IWorkbenchPage page, IPerspectiveDescriptor perspective, String changeId) {
    try {
      page.showView("...", null, IWorkbenchPage.VIEW_VISIBLE);
    } catch (PartInitException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void perspectiveActivated(IWorkbenchPage page, IPerspectiveDescriptor perspective) {
  }
});
```

EDIT: since this is tied to view1 you could place this code in the Activator for the view1 plugin.  Of course it won't show up until some code is loaded from the view1 plugin.  Something like:

```
Job job = new UIJob("Add Perspective listener") {
    public IStatus runInUIThread(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
        addPerspectiveListener();
        return Status.OK_STATUS;
    }
};
job.setSystem(true);
job.schedule();
```

Comment: We tried using the above logic but we are not able to get the execution control inside the implemented methods. Looks like the listerner is not getting registered. Any information how we need to add this listener?

Comment: The above code has been lifted out of our code base... The `perspectiveChanged(...)` method should be invoked whenever the perspective changes.