# Adding a view to a folder in perspective - runtime

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I want to achieve something during run time.

I have a customized editor plugin. Now, what I want is whenever someone opens this editor, there should be a view displayed in bottom folder no matter what the current perspective is.

What I meant from above is, say currently "Java" perspective is shown on active page , so whenever someone opens my custom editor, I want to add a view in bottom folder(where we see "Problems" tab). Similarly, for any current perspective, my view should get rendered as soon as my custom editor is opened.

I know about initial layout and adding a place holder view, but I can not add place holder to each and every perspective. I want this to work for any perspective opened.

Can someone please suggest workaround for this ? 
Thanks in Advance !

Comment: Well you can call `IWorkbenchPage.showView` to show any view, but I'm not sure there is any way to control where it will appear if it is not in the perspective.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412448/how-to-add-perspective-listeners